# How is the computation of integral image in OpenCV so efficient?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I compared the runtime of the `cv::integral()` with my simple textbook implementation of the integral image (see the code below) and found out that `cv::integral()` is almost 50 times faster. I was wondering how is it computed in OpenCV so efficiently. I checked their github [repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/3rdparty/carotene/src/integral.cpp) but couldn't understand what's going on there.

```
cv::Mat integralImage(const cv::Mat& img)
{
    CV_Assert(img.type() == CV_8UC1);

    int nRows = img.rows;
    int nCols = img.cols;

    cv::Mat S = cv::Mat::zeros(nRows + 1, nCols + 1, CV_32SC1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= nRows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= nCols; ++j)
        {
            S.ptr<int>(i)[j] = S.ptr<int>(i)[j - 1] + S.ptr<int>(i - 1)[j] \
                 - S.ptr<int>(i - 1)[j - 1] + int(img.ptr<uchar>(i - 1)[j - 1]);
        }
    }
    return S;
}
```

Comment: `S.ptr<int>(i)` is expensive. Try fetching a pointer to the image data and doing pointer arithmetic instead. Another speed gain can be had by remembering one value from the previous iteration on the row, significantly simplifying your computations. The last 2x or so factor probably will come from using SIMD instructions.

Comment: @CrisLuengo indeed that helped a lot. Now my code is 10x faster, but still ~4x slower than the OpenCV. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the right optimization options for the compiler? GCC can do simple vectorization and loop unrolling for you.

Comment: No I wasn't specifying any optimization options. Now that I tried it, my two versions of code run almost as fast as the OpenCV's function. Thank you very much! I think the question can be closed now or I would gladly accept your answer if I could.

Comment: A nice way can also be to have a look at opencv source code.

Comment: opencv probably uses multithreading. besides SIMD instructions, that makes a lot of difference. an integral image, IIRC, is built from simple cumulative sums along each row and each column. that is trivial to calculate in a tiny amount of registers, and it's embarrassingly trivial to parallelize with SIMD and with multiple cores.

Comment: @Micka here it is https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/3rdparty/carotene/src/integral.cpp
I had a look at it but there are no comments which makes it very difficult to understand.

Comment: Carotene is an acceleration for ARM as far as I remember. You can see all those vaddq_u16 etc. Instructions